# Phantoms error when run as child process

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm getting the following error when running phantomjs as a child process within node:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ./phantomjs /Users/ababu/node-phantom/pdfgeneratorfromurl/makeImageLogin.js https://app.datadoghq.com/screen/35069/production-databases?tv_mode=true
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the crash reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/crash-reporting.html> and file a bug report at
<https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/new>.
Please attach the crash dump file:
  /var/folders/q2/j7xwnq512ts7x75ymv0rlhq0w_4zqk/T//DFF3A303-FFE1-40F2-8ECA-A6B2F43D9160.dmp
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c ./phantomjs /Users/ababu/node-phantom/pdfgeneratorfromurl/makeImageLogin.js https://app.datadoghq.com/screen/35069/production-databases?tv_mode=true' }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks. This is using phantomjs v2.0 which is not an official release.

Comment: Error messages like that are largely unhelpful. What happens when you run this command from the command line? Did this time out? Please provide as much information as you can.

Comment: It seems to be running fine when I run it from the command line, but it fails when phantomjs is running as a child process, lot of client requests coming in to the node service is causing this.

Comment: Honestly, with just this information, the only thing I can think of is that your server is timing out on the request. Try doing `server.timeout = 0` in whatever file is creating your server.

Comment: server.timeout is not related in this case because it's not related to the response to the client, the client gets a string as the response, the other part of the route is that it makes a call to another node service which spawns phantomjs and does some scraping and stores it to db., the main service does not wait on the call to the node service running the phantom child